# Understanding plot showing impedance, resistance, and reactance

Tags: sensor, analog, impedance

I am looking at a part of the datasheet for a hydrophone I am using in a project. It includes this figure, which plots resistance, impedance, and reactance vs. frequency:

[image]

Part of my project involves designing a preamplifier for the hydrophone. Because the output of the hydrophone will be in the range of 20 to 40 kHz, I must make the input impedance of the preamplifier much greater than that of the internal resistance of the hydrophone to maximize voltage transfer between the two.

When looking at this chart, I am unsure of which value I need to use for the equivalent series impedance. The parallel capacitance of the hydrophone is 3.4 nF, and its datasheet can be found [here](https://www.m-b-t.com/fileadmin/redakteur/Ozeanographie/Hydrophone/Produktblaetter/TC4013.pdf).

Comment: It looks like the curves match up with your statement about the parallel capacitance. No surprises there. Do you know how to calculate this? (\$\mid\, X_C \mid =\frac1{2\pi\,f\,C}\$) If you use that equation I think you'll find that the red line matches the magnitude (the sign of capacitance reactance is taken as negative.) The resistance looks very low at your frequencies of interest, but the reactance will vary by a factor of two over the range.

Comment: I'm good with impedance of a capacitor, but is the capacitor is in parallel with the hydrophone then I'm confused with how to factor this into my circuit diagram. Considering that the resistance is small, could I model the hydrophone as a voltage source in shunt with a capacitor to ground, neglecting series resistance (because its small).

Comment: I think you should consider looking for hydrophone circuits developed by Winfield Hill, as an example. This is smack in the middle of what he's done in his life, so I'm sure there must be something out there with his name on it. However, my instincts say you need a JFET for the 1st stage/pre-amp (lower noise at the required impedance.) In fact, I'm almost sure of it. That can be followed up with a shielded twisted pair wire to whatever you need (if you need circuitry remote from the hydrophone.)

Comment: I will look into his work. I have a textbook of his as well which I can look through.

Comment: I found one possibly useful reference: Miguel Alvarado, *"Construction and Testing of Low Noise Hydrophones,"* Naval Postgraduate School, Master’s Thesis, 2003, p. 8. But I have a question for you. Why haven't you contacted the manufacturer? They will know and will likely have a white paper on the topic, if not both that and also a reference design for you.

Comment: Here's some more info: [DIY Hydrophone](http://karlgrabe.com/sounds.htm) and [Example pre-amplifier](http://karlgrabe.com/sounds/hydrophone/Hydrophone/preamp2.pdf) for [this DIY hydrophone](http://karlgrabe.com/sounds/hydrophone/Hydrophone/bender2.pdf). Also look on page 28 in the following PDF: [Construction and Testing of Low-Noise Hydrophones](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a424808.pdf). It really does NOT take a lot of searching to find this stuff. I think you should have gotten this far on your own and told us about it. Your question would have been so much better!

Comment: As the impedance is almost entirely the negative of the reactance, the modelled resistance and capacitance are in series, not in parallel. This means that to a good first approximation, you can take the hydrophone source as a pure capacitor.

Comment: That datasheet is really poor on impedance topic. Reactance and impedance are exactly the same due the low resistive component. Resistive component can't be read due unfit scale, scales should have been logarithmic....I can hardly imagine a worst documented impedance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the impedance is about 1K-2K through your band of interest.  I don't know what you mean by "much more," but 20K input impedance for your preamp should probably be easily achievable, and 200K wouldn't be much of a challenge.  Note that your internal *resistance* is significantly lower--almost negligible--but the *impedance* will still affect both the output level and (perhaps more significantly) the phase shift.  If phase shift is critical (which I doubt, but you're the expert on your requirements) it could be compensated for in the preamp.